# How to augment the declarative base in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am following the SQLAlchemy Documentation by Mike Bayer and have a couple of issues when trying to augment the declarative_base as per code below.

module db.base

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String

class Base(object):
    @classmethod
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        print(">>__tablename__() "+str(cls.__name__.lower()))
        return cls.__name__.lower()
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable = False)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

module db.dbtest

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from db.base import Base
engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/test.db', echo=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                autoflush=False,
                                bind=engine))

def init_db():
    import db.model.testdata 
    base = Base()
    base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   init_db()
```

module db.model.testdata

```
from db.base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import REAL

class TestData(Base):
    name = Column(String(255), nullable = False)
    creationDate =  Column(Date, index=True)
    updateDate =  Column(Date, index=True)
    miscData = Column(REAL, nullable = True)
```

In the SQLAlchemy documentation the @classmethod annotation is not added to the tablename method in the Base class. However without it I get a "Method 'tablename - db.base' should have self as first parameter" error, basically saying that the @declared_attr is not marking the method as a class level method. Are you supposed to add @classmethod or is this a bug in the version (0.9.8) I am using?

The tablename returned by the base augmentor is cryptic "bound method DeclarativeMeta.? of class db.model.testdata.TestData" How can I get just the class name (TestData) returned?

Another minor issue - the print() call in the tablename method in the Base class does not print anything (neither did logger) and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I still get an 'Method tablename - db.base should have self as first
>   parameter' error marker on the code but it runs OK now.

If that bothers you, having the cursos over the error pointed by PyDev, you can press `Control+1` and mark the line as `# @NoSelf`. This informs PyDev that your method does not have self as its first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting a cryptic table name generated and why the print call wasn't working was that the tablename method in the Base class was not being called (due to having the @classmethod annotation).

The issue appears to be with PyDev. I ran the same code in PyCharm, PyCharm did not have an issue with the @declared_attr annotation and did not require @classmethod.

In PyDev, I added sqlalchemy to the forced builtins (Window ->Preferences ->PyDev ->Interpreters ->Python interpreter ->Forced Builtins). I then removed the @classmethod anotation and re-ran it. I still get an 'Method **tablename** - db.base should have self as first parameter' error marker on the code but it runs OK now.